# Check Value from mysql using android

Tags: android, mysql

I have a table which has a field called `Sold` , in that field i store 0 and 1.
So 1 means sold and 0 mean Available.

K, my problem is that ,I want to change 0 to available and 1 to sold when i diplay information into my emulator , here what i tried but it returning sold even though i have 0 in my database :

```
if (sold.length()==0){

    Log.d("checking","Inside = 0");

    val = "Available";}

    else if (sold.length()>0)

        Log.d("checking","Inside = 1");
        val = "Sold
```

And **sold** contains a value from a database.

please help to change 0 to Available and 1 to Sold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(sold.equalIgnoreCase("0"))
{
   Log.d("checking","Inside = 0");
}else
{
   Log.d("checking","Inside = 1");
}
```

Comment: You are a King parag..tanx alot :)

Comment: Its my pleasure  that i useful to u.

Answer (score 2):

The sold.length you have there is the actual length of the String representation "sold" that you are using. Meaning that if you have the word "some" this .length() equals 4.

So in your snippet the sold variable is the "0" or "1" respectively so the sold.length() always equals to 1. Try to cast the String variable into an Integer and make the comparison or even better try to make the variable into Integer from the beginning.

Comment: Tanx dude, but parag just gave me what i was looking for, but atleast i also gave you one for making me understand